# How do I change the decoder feature type in Tensorflow Datasets?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to do some augmentations to tensorflow image datasets such as cifar and others from here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/

Now I have a mapping function that actually another user from SO helped me with that works with my own dataset:

```
def map_data(inputs):
    image = inputs['image']
    image = tf.numpy_function(func=aug_fn, inp=[image], Tout=tf.float32)
    image = image / 255.0

    labels = inputs['label']
    labels = tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes)

return {'image_input': image, 'label': labels}, labels
```

now when iterating over the dataset I get this error:

```
ValueError: Missing data for input "image_input". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['image', 'label']. Expected the following keys: ['image_input', 'label']
```

which makes sense because the decoder returns uint8 type.

But I couldn't find any info or examples in the docs on how to change that.

Can I somehow just access the decoder Object's attributes?

I tried like in the API https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/decode/Decoder?hl=cs

but it doesn't work.

thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If it is augmentation you want to use, you should use these layers in the top of your model

```
    data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1),
    ])
```

For the scaling, you use this line

```
rescale = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1. / 255)
```

This should work smoothly in your model. Here an example of a model with augmentation and rescaling

```
    model = Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1. / 255, input_shape=(256, 256, 3)),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
```

Comment: Hi Amel, thank you, I am aware of these layers and have used them before, but there are a lot of things I do with albumentations that I can not with these layers. Thanks though.